# Express.js - How to send alert from Express to Client using res.render? Not res.send

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to send the alert message to client.

So, I found that.

res.send(<'alert("XXX!!!")');

In this way, I didn't use res.render();

I want to use together.

Or

I want to send alert message using res.render();

How do I this?

This is the code.

```js
   if (err)
    console.log(err);
   
   if (flag === 1) { //함수 이름 중복
    try {
     //res.send('<script>alert("함수 이름 중복!")</script>');
     LoadDB(res);
    } catch (exception) {}
   }
   else {
    //(4) 데이터베이스 insert 쿼리
    var query = "insert into automation_script set ?";
    conn.query(query, set, function (error, result, fields) {
     if (error) {
      console.log('Insert_DB error' + error);
     } else {
      try {
       LoadDB(res);
      } catch (exception) {}
     }
    });
   }
   //(5) 데이터베이스 해제
   conn.end();
```

Thanks you.

Comment: how about sending your alert as text and at client side use eval() to execute prior to that why such need ?

Comment: @VinodLouis isn't `eval` a bad idea?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen ofcourse it is if adulterated thats why I asked why such need

Comment: @VinodLouis eval? Oh! I have to research the eval. Thanks you!

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542357/how-to-use-sweetalert-in-nodejs/59696880#59696880

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of problems here. For one I'm not sure you understand how try catch blocks work. You have an unnecessary amount of ifs that aren't being handled too. Those problems aside, the answer to the question you asked is a websocket. From the looks of your code and question, I think what you're really looking for is how to send a response from an http get request in express. There are many ways to solve the problem you are asking to be solved. From the code I see above I don't think you have a good understanding of client/server models and It would be to your benefit to read up on how http works. I also can't answer your question because the code snippet you pasted does not provide enough context to answer your question. Most importantly though, alert is not a function in node. calling alert does nothing. In fact when you do res(alert("something")), if alert is defined in your global namespace (I hope it isn't), you are sending back undefined. There is such a thing as isomorphism, however, web api functions are exclusive to the client. I hope that helps.

Comment: First, Thanks you Jamie. I will remember your advice. In fact, I'm novice programmer especially javascript and node.js. But, I got the project that I had to make using javascript and node.js. It's hard but interesting. I will research the http and web socket. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

res.send(`<script>alert("your alert message"); window.location.href = "/page_location"; </script>`);

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

res.send("alert("your alert message"); window.location.href = "/page_location"; ");

same answer as M.HUSSAIN only he forgot the string quotes aroud the expression