# How to use sweetalert in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, sweetalert2

I have a nodejs code given with html code, I want to show a sweet alert on client side,after process a function in nodejs?.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const Swal = require('sweetalert2');

router.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {

    Swal('Hello world!');

});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt_br">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="text-center title-1"> Cad </h1>
    <form action="/add" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sweet Alert is supposed to be used in the browser, not on the server, you need to include it in your client side code instead.

Comment: I know that, but how, i have tried ajax...i want to know any other method?@m90

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the only way you can show a popup swal

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {

   res.json("Hello world!")
});


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt_br">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="text-center title-1"> Cad </h1>
    <form id="form" action="#" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script>

//import JQuery from script
//import swal script

$("#form").on("submit", function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
  url: "/add",
  method: "post"
}).done(d=>{
  swal(e.responseJSON);
});
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you can do using EJS

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {
   res.status(201).render('new', { isAdded : true } );
});
```

In HTML side

```
<% if (isAdded) { %>
 <script>
  Swal.fire(
     'Good job!',
     'Data saved',
     'success'
 )
</script>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to deal with this, you can use query parameters.

So, Here is what you can do

**On the server**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/login', (req, res)=>{
   res.redirect("/login?success=true&message=Logged In Successfully")
});
```

**On the Client-Side (EJS)**

```
    <script>
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    if(urlParams.has('success') && urlParams.get('success')){
    swal({
    title: "Failed",
    text: `${message}`, 
    icon: "error",
    button: "Okay",
    }).then(()=>{
        console.log(window.location.hostname)
    window.location.replace(window.location.origin + '/login');

    })
}
```

This will simply popup swal. And you can toggle the value of success to render error and success messages.